# Why UIScrollBar flash component doesn't work properly in FireFox and Chrome but works in IE?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs5

I have created a flash application and use UIScrollBar component for scrolling texts in it. I have exported swf and used in my html file.
It works properly in IE9 or IE10 but doesn't work in FireFox or Chrome.

[image]
firefox

[image]
IE

Answer (score 0):

Give an instance name to your UIScrollbar.Then add this line of code into your function:

```
  myScrollBar.update();
```

Sometimes, for whatever reason, after the SWF is loaded and the text is there, the scrollbar doesn't scroll or even show scroll buttons. The built-in update() function just updates the scrollbar after the loading so that it recognizes the text in the textfield and will then scroll.